# How to measure similarity of two data

Tags: probability, statistics

I am measuring the similarity of two data with same size is 20. That is

```
A=[0.915450999999999    0.908220499999997   0.900374999999996   0.890547499999996   0.880455499999997   0.868436999999998   0.853787499999999   0.836066499999999   0.815514999999999   0.785924499999999   0.661612000000002   0.208405500000000   0.0495730000000000  0.0148525000000000  0.00604500000000001 0.00292150000000000 0.00150100000000000 0.000730999999999999    0.000431999999999999    0.000222999999999999]
```

and

```
B=[0.915971250000000    0.909765000000000   0.902468749999999   0.894108749999999   0.883719999999998   0.871347499999999   0.857477500000000   0.841131250000000   0.821846250000000   0.796526250000000   0.673128750000000   0.208027500000000   0.0520962500000000  0.0187462500000000  0.00634375000000000 0.00295500000000000 0.00134500000000000 0.000226250000000000    0.000150000000000000    0.000113750000000000]
```

[image]
Could you help me to calculate it in matlab? The result shows 1 if they are similar, otherwise, 0 is different.

Thank in advance.

Comment: What exactly does it mean for data to be similar?

Comment: Yes. I have two data. First, it is my result A and second is reference result B. I want to compare the similarity of my result and reference result. The similarity that means the similar of two data

Comment: but what is the definition of two datasets being similar? Is $[0.9,0.8]$ similar to $[0.901,0.801]$? Is it similar to $[0.91,0.81]$? Or to $[0.85,0.85]$?

Comment: I think [0.9,0.8]  similar to [0.901,0.801] more similar. You can think it looks like mean square distance between two data

Comment: Is this an "open" question, where you don't know beforehand what it means for data to be similar, but you have to come up with a reasonable choice of definition? You mention "square distance". If $A$ and $B$ are datasets, does it make sense to say that they are *similar*, if their square distance is less than some number $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 0):

We have to define "similarity" first.

Say, if we have only 1 pair of data, $a_1$ and $b_1$, then have an absolute distance between them $$e_1=|a_1-b_1|$$ 
And we need to have a criterion that, $$if \; (e_1 < \varepsilon) \; then \; \rm{Similarity = True}$$

For $n$ pairs of data, we just sum the errors of all pairs and take the average of they. $$e={1 \over n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} |a_i-b_i|$$

$$if \; (e < \varepsilon) \; then \; \rm{Similarity = True}$$